# Cannot implement type XYZ with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, collections

I have the following class:

```
public class CommentList 
{
    string ItemType;
    string Comment1;
    string Status1;
    string DiscussionBoardId;
    Guid CourseId;
    Guid CommentID;
}
```

I'm trying to do the following LINQ statement:

```
List<CommentList> query=
    from c in db.Comments
    join s in db.Status on c.StatusId equals s.StatusId
    join d in db.DiscussionBoards 
        on c.DiscussionBoardId equals d.DiscussionBoardId
    where d.CourseId=="CourseID"
    orderby d.ItemType, d.DiscussionBoardId
    select new CommentList {
        d.ItemType,
        c.Comment1,
        s.Status1,
        c.DiscussionBoardId,
        d.CourseId,
        c.CommentID
    };
```

The problem is, the editor is complaining on the first parenthesis of the select statement. It's saying:

> Cannot implement type 'CommentList' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.

Can someone help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Make your fields `public` because they are not accessible as they are now.

```
public class CommentList
{
  public string ItemType;
  public string Comment1;
  public string Status1;
  public string DiscussionBoardId;
  public Guid CourseId;
  public Guid CommentID;
}
```

And explicity set them in your initializer.

```
select new CommentList
{
    ItemType = d.ItemType,
    Comment1 = c.Comment1,
    Status1 = s.Status1,
    DiscussionBoardId = c.DiscussionBoardId,
    CourseId = d.CourseId,
    CommentID = c.CommentID
};
```

Comment: Good catch, Jeffery!  Until I set the properties to Public, it wouldn't work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Just a fuller follow-up to my comment. What you are trying to do is [use object initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx), which requires you to name the properties.  What it thinks you are trying is [collection initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531208.aspx)

```
List<CommentList> query = from c in db.Comments
                join s in db.Status on c.StatusId equals s.StatusId
                join d in db.DiscussionBoards on c.DiscussionBoardId equals d.DiscussionBoardId
                where d.CourseId == "CourseID"
                orderby d.ItemType, d.DiscussionBoardId
                select new CommentList
                {
                    ItemType = d.ItemType,
                    Comment1 = c.Comment1,
                    Status1= s.Status1,
                    DiscussionBoardId = c.DiscussionBoardId,
                    CourseId = d.CourseId,
                    CommentId = c.CommentID
                };
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, Justin!

Comment: @JavaRox I added another on collection initialization, which is what it thinks you are trying

Comment: This was my issue. It is confusing because if you often work with anonymous types, it tells warns you that the property names are superfluous, and then you go back to a fixed type and get caught in this.

Answer (score 9):

Your initialization is not correct. You need to assign values to explicit properties.

```
select new CommentList
{
    ItemType = d.ItemType,
    Comment1 = c.Comment1,
    Status1 = s.Status1,
    DiscussionBoardId = c.DiscussionBoardId,
    CourseId = d.CourseId,
    CommentID = c.CommentID
};
```

Comment: That's it!  I appreciate it!  Whew, seems like I learn something new every day!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can only infer property names when creating anonymous types.

You need to explicitly assign your properties:

```
new CommentList {
    ItemType = d.ItemType, 
    ...
```